# Код для ESP32, считывание меток и отображение в веб сервере

Tags: c#, esp32

Хочу создать проект.
Задача проекта.
Оборудование-ESP32 и One Wire 125Khz считыватель.
Считывание меток 125Кгц, где у каждого номера метки в коде будет присвоено имя.
Считывание будет привязано к дате и времени.
Данные будут выводится в веб сервере есп32.
Желательно в виде строк, пример. Дата, присвоенное метке имя: Вася, время первой регистрации и последней.
Объём хранения данных до 3 месяцев. Потом перезапись.

Вопрос.
Как выстроить структуру лучше, надо ли добавлять чип памяти, на что обратить вниамние, какие готовые данные искать для проекта

Сам учу С++ и Питон, знаю PHP, HTML, CSS.

Comment: Слишком абстрактный вопрос, что пробовали, что получается, что не получается? При чем тут C#? На текущий вопрос объективно ответить либо сложно, либо вообще невозможно. Можно только догадки гадать.

Comment: Пробовал сделать веб сервер.
Добавил считыватель меток как оборудование.
К тестовой метке добавил имя.
Данные считываются, но не смог добиться привязки считывания к дате и времени а также формированию таблицы

Comment: Легче не стало.